# Generate desugared library for B4A

Tags: android, android-studio, android-d8, vb4android, jdk-desugaring

I'm making an Android library for B4A framework.
Here's the **situation**:

- My Android library uses Java8 features (such as Lambda)
- B4A (Basic4Android) uses legacy `dex` (instead of `d8`) to make the apps and thus, **incompatible with java8** and will not desugar by itself.

Using my `aar` file in the B4A results to the following error:

```
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
  invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
...
```

The solution of the official forum is to desugar the Jar of the library using [**Bazel's desugar tool**](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2975), but it seems it leads to `Expected a load for ...` which is a different error and not my question.

**My question:**
Is it possible to generate desugared `aar` library (compatible with Java7 and no lambda) using Android Studio, for these cases?

I know that `d8` does the desugaring, but it's output is `.dex` files and not `.jar` file.

**What I've tried:**
Solution said in the Android's [Using Java 8 Feature](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) did not help because it does not produce compatible jar and the error still occurs.